# How to solve overload error in tanstack infinite query?

Tags: typescript, tanstackreact-query

```
export const useGetPosts = () => {
  return useInfiniteQuery({
    queryKey: [QUERY_KEYS.GET_INFINITE_POSTS],
    queryFn: getInfinitePosts,
    getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => {
      if (lastPage && lastPage.documents.length === 0) {
        return null;
      }
      const lastId = lastPage?.documents[lastPage?.documents.length - 1].$id;

      return lastId;
    },
  });
};
```

Getting the error at the time of deployment in this function

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(options: UndefinedInitialDataInfiniteOptions<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, Error, InfiniteData<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, unknown>, QUERY_KEYS[], number>, queryClient?: QueryClient | undefined): UseInfiniteQueryResult<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '(lastPage: DocumentList<Document> | undefined) => string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'GetNextPageParamFunction<number, DocumentList<Document> | undefined>'.
      Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number | null | undefined'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(options: DefinedInitialDataInfiniteOptions<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, Error, InfiniteData<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, unknown>, QUERY_KEYS[], number>, queryClient?: QueryClient | undefined): DefinedUseInfiniteQueryResult<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '(lastPage: DocumentList<Document> | undefined) => string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'GetNextPageParamFunction<number, DocumentList<Document> | undefined>'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(options: UseInfiniteQueryOptions<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, Error, InfiniteData<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, unknown>, DocumentList<...> | undefined, QUERY_KEYS[], number>, queryClient?: QueryClient | undefined): UseInfiniteQueryResult<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '(lastPage: DocumentList<Document> | undefined) => string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'GetNextPageParamFunction<number, DocumentList<Document> | undefined>'.ts(2769)
queryClient-5b892aba.d.ts(335, 5): The expected type comes from property 'getNextPageParam' which is declared here on type 'UndefinedInitialDataInfiniteOptions<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, Error, InfiniteData<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, unknown>, QUERY_KEYS[], number>'
queryClient-5b892aba.d.ts(335, 5): The expected type comes from property 'getNextPageParam' which is declared here on type 'DefinedInitialDataInfiniteOptions<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, Error, InfiniteData<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, unknown>, QUERY_KEYS[], number>'
queryClient-5b892aba.d.ts(335, 5): The expected type comes from property 'getNextPageParam' which is declared here on type 'UseInfiniteQueryOptions<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, Error, InfiniteData<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, unknown>, DocumentList<...> | undefined, QUERY_KEYS[], number>'
(property) getNextPageParam: GetNextPageParamFunction<number, Models.DocumentList<Models.Document> | undefined>
This function can be set to automatically get the next cursor for infinite queries. The result will also be used to determine the value of hasNextPage.
```

This is the infinite posts function.

```
export async function getInfinitePosts({ pageParam }: { pageParam: number }) {
  const queries: any[] = [Query.orderDesc("$updatedAt"), Query.limit(10)];

  if (pageParam) {
    queries.push(Query.cursorAfter(pageParam.toString()));
  }

  try {
    const posts = await databases.listDocuments(
      appwriteConfig.databaseId,
      appwriteConfig.postCollectionId,
      queries
    );

    if (!posts) throw Error;

    return posts;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

I am using the useGetPosts function in a component as

```
const { data: posts, fetchNextPage, hasNextPage } = useGetPosts();
```

I am providing the github link for the project incase anyone want to view the codebase : https://github.com/CodeWithYashp/snapgram

I have read the docs but still can't find why am i getting this error

Answer (score 1):

Js mastery did his video in tanstack query v4. In v5 there is a initialpage param required. Try this, worked for me:

```
export const useGetPosts = () => {
return useInfiniteQuery({
  queryKey: [QUERY_KEYS.GET_INFINITE_POSTS],
  queryFn: getInfinitePosts as any,
  getNextPageParam: (lastPage: any) => {
    if (!lastPage || lastPage.documents.length === 0) {
      return null;
    }

    const lastId = lastPage.documents[lastPage.documents.length - 1].$id;
    return lastId;
  },
  initialPageParam: null, // Set initialPageParam to null
});
```

};